# Firefox focus from developer tools to browser and vice versa

Tags: macos, firefox, shortcut, firefox-developer-tools

My Firefox developer tools are always in a separate window. I open them up on my mac with option-cmd-I. But then I am stuck there and I haven't found a shortcut to get back to the browser, except for pressing option-com-I again. But then then the developer tools are being closed.

But that's not what I want. I'd like a shortcut which takes me back to the browser window while the developer tools are still visible.

Answer (score 0):

As described on [the dedicated Firefox documentation page](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/keyboard_shortcuts/index.html#id1), you can use the `cmd+opt+k` shortcut for focusing on open Developer Tools in Firefox without closing them.